# Compare two date/times with tolerance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially, I have two columns of data and I would like to know if a given value in Column A matches any value in Column B within a certain delta value.

I don't think an approximated VLOOKUP would do the trick here. The values are dates and times of day (as in `8/12/14 1:43:02 PM`) and I want the delta value to be <15 seconds.

So if `A1` is `8/12/14 1:43:02 PM` and `B156` is `8/12/14 1:43:08 PM`, return a boolean.

Comment: VBA has a nice [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx) function for this sort of thing.

Comment: If you don't have too many dates in one column, you can transpose that column and make it the column headers of a table.  Make the values of the table the difference between the column headers (your transposed date column) and the row headers (your other date column).  The table values can be something like `=abs(B$1-$A2)`.  Then look for differences less than your delta value your favorite way.  Heat map.  Conditional formatting.  An equation like `=abs(B$1-$A2)<10` (difference < 10 days).

Comment: I would sort column B and use [MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx). Then the matched value and the following would be good candidates to check. For the test, remember dates are stored as numbers: 1 is a full day, 1/86400 is 1 second.

Comment: Yes, both columns are sorted. Here's what I used to match the time, but I'm stumped by the month/day because those need to match. In the meantime, I'll take a look at your suggestions and see if they're easier to implement than converting m/d/hr/min/sec to secs. 
'=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$17164,">="&B2-TIME(0,0,15), $A$2:$A$17164,"<="&B2+TIME(0,0,15))'

Comment: @pnuts. You need only the nearest below, and check this one and the following. It will answer the question (*does it match any value within 15 sec?*)

Comment: @seahawks506 Check the whole date-time value: the integer part holds the date, the fraction part the time. And just remember 1 day = 86400 seconds.

Comment: @pnuts. Yes, but you only have to find one. So the nearest below and the following are obviously enough to test if there is at least one, or none.

Comment: @pnuts. Only the OP can tell, but as is, "*if a given value in Column A matches any value in Column B within a certain delta value*" does not ask for the specific values, it only ask if there is any. And since he wants a boolean, anyway...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I meant that in the formula, I'm checking column A against column B one A-value at a time. I think your advice to convert time to a decimal value makes sense; how would you guys suggest I write a formula to add a calendar date+time to arrive at the decimal #? Wouldn't have to be super accurate as the numbers only matter relative to each other.

Comment: True, thanks for the clarification- I'm relatively new to excel and still learning. Would my COUNTIFS solution work given that the value as a whole is treated as TIME or does it need tweaking?

Comment: @seahawks506 If you exchange A and B, it does work.

Comment: Thanks for your input, you all have been so much help! I hope I will be able to pay it forward in the future when I know more about excel.

Answer (score 1):

Since comments tend to get long, here is a long comment, or a short answer.

To compare timestamps, you can write `=ABS(A1-B1)<1/5760`. Numeric conversion is automatic, and `1/5760=15/86400`, or 15 seconds, considering that for Excel, a day equals 1.

Here is an example, for one value in column A.

[image]

My Excel is french, `VRAI` means `TRUE`. The date/time format is maybe not the same as yours, but it's only visual.

In english, the formula are:

- C1: `=MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$21)`
- D1: `=INDEX($B$1:$B$21,C1)`
- E1: `=INDEX($B$1:$B$21,C1+1)`
- F1: `=OR(ABS(D1-A1)<1/5760,ABS(E1-A1)<1/5760)`

Of course, you don't really need 4 columns to do this, but it's easier to understand.

See also the help for [MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) function: *MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending order*.

So you get the index of the value just before, and you have to test this value (first part of the `OR`, and D1) and the next value (second part, and E1).

Comment: Thanks Jean-Claude! Do you think there could be mismatched data because MATCH does not find a value larger than lookup_value?

Comment: @seahawks506 In that case, `MATCH` returns the index of the last value in column B. It won't hurt to check it, and checking the "following" will cause an error (because `INDEX` will "overflow"), but you can guard against it with an `IFERROR`. For example, write in E1: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$21,C1+1),0)`. The 0 will then be compared with A1, but the difference won't be less than 15 seconds, and it does no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,ABS(A2-TIME_RANGE)<EQ_15_SEC,0),"not found")
```

This will return either the index of the item in column B that satisfies the 15 second rule, or "not found".

`TIME_RANGE` is one range of values you want to check, like column B

`A2` is the candidate in column A on this row. You can fill the formula down.

`EQ_15_SEC` just points to a cell where I did the calculation `=15/60/60/24`

This is an array formula, so commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (not just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks for the help Andy, can you explain the EQ_15_sec? What is this calculation converting?

Comment: It converts 15 seconds to a fraction of a date. In Excel each increment of 1 represents 1 day. It's not necessary to do it this way, I just prefer to have some calculations stored in other cells sometimes.